# How to align a background image with padding?

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div>` with a left aligned background image and some text.

I need the div (or an inner div) to have some padding so the text will start next to background image, not on it. Is there a way to do this with CSS?

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hctkr1p2/1/) and the CSS:

```
.mydiv {
  background-image: url('http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/d/d6/Human_NEGAS.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20090709062312');
  background-position: left bottom;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 500px;
  height: 700px;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the text will start next to background image, not on it"?

Comment: I guess that you don't want the text to be on image, rather beneath the image. Am I right?

Comment: If you don't want the text ON the image, why is the image a background?

Comment: Can you please clarify exactly what it is you're trying to achieve as it isn't very clear from your question?

Comment: I want the text starting next to image (on the right side of the background image), not on the image. The reason I want the image background because I want it to be a fixed background located bottom-left corner. I want the background image contained because I want the width of the image automatically calculated. That's why I can't use an image inside the div.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flexbox and a pseudo-element could do this...*assuming I have your intention right*.

> I need the div (or inner div) has some padding so the text will start next to background image, not on it

Basically, the inner div is 100% height of the parent element but any space *after* the text is taken up by the pseudo-element which has the image as a background.

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.mydiv {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
.mydiv div {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}
.mydiv div:after {
  content: '';
  background-image: url('http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/d/d6/Human_NEGAS.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20090709062312');
  background-position: left bottom;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="mydiv">
  <div>My Text here</div>
</div>
```

**REVISION/ALTERNATE** after commented requirements updated

> I want the text starting next to image (on the right side of the background image), not on the image. The reason I want the image background because I want it to be a fixed background located bottom-left corner. I want the background image contained because I want the width of the image automatically calculated.

You would need to change the structure and put the image inline

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.mydiv {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}
.imgdiv {
  height: 100%;
}
.imgdiv img {
  max-height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.textdiv {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="mydiv">
  <div class="imgdiv">
    <img src="http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/d/d6/Human_NEGAS.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20090709062312" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="textdiv">My Text here</div>
</div>
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/z425h9ft/)

Comment: Based on the clarification provided by @MeCe in the question comments, I think using `::before` instead of `::after` here is the solution being looked for.

Comment: No, unfortunately not. The pseudo-element needs to be able to calculate a width and that can't be done with flexbox as the text div will just take up all the space leaving none for the pseudo-element.

Comment: I think I got the idea. I get that what I want is actually not possible with only CSS. I think I can work with the inner image, maybe make it parallax or something. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

No need for 2 div , you can achieve all with only one in a very simple way
Try this code:

```
.mydiv {
    background-image: url('http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/d/d6/Human_NEGAS.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20090709062312');
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-size: 250px  auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 500px;
    height: 700px;
    padding-left: 255px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I didn't think to try it with pixel background size.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the text not to appear on the background image but below it, I have two solutions:

**First:**

Use separate div for background image like

```css
.mydiv {
  background-image: url('http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/d/d6/Human_NEGAS.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20090709062312');
  background-position: left bottom;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="mydiv"></div><div>My Text here</div>
```

**Second:**

Apply the following CSS to the div containing text.

```css
.mydiv {
  background-image: url('http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/d/d6/Human_NEGAS.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20090709062312');
  background-position: left bottom;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
#innerText {
  padding-top: 105vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="mydiv"><div id="innerText">My Text here</div></div>
```